# How can I remove the date and time from a string IF it contains it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of strings.  Some of them contain a date and timestamp at the end, but most don't. The date/time format will always be the same format.

```
sampleString = ['String 1', 'String2', 'String 3 05.24.2019 04:48:24']
```

I am looking for a statement like this:

```
if 'MM.DD.YYYY' in sampleString:
    samplestring = samplestring.split('MM.DD.YYYY')[0]

print(sampleString)
>>>['String 1', 'String2', 'String 3']
```

But that is clearly not working. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can use the `search` function from the `re` module

```
import re
data = ['String 1', 'String2', 'String 3 05.24.2019 04:48:24']
pattern = re.compile(r"\b\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\b")
print([pattern.split(i)[0].strip() if pattern.search(i) else i for i in data])
```

**Output:**

```
['String 1', 'String2', 'String 3']
```

Comment: I think this is removing the data/time from my strings like i would like, but it is returning ['S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '1', etc.....]

Comment: I was able to make yours work by removing the 'i for i in' statement at the end and replacing the split(i) and the search(i) with my variable (It is in a for loop already, grabbing each variable in the list).  Also. Could you explain to me how (r"\b\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\b") works?

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

input = ['String 1', 'String2', 'String 3 05.24.2019 04:48:24']

# compile our regex
r = re.compile(r'(.+) \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$')

# take first part
output = [r.sub(r'\1', s) for s in ls]

print(ls)
# ['String 1', 'String2', 'String 3']
```

clarification for regex:

- `\d`: matches any number
- `\.`: literal dot
- `{n}`: repeat the previous token exactly n times
- `$`: matches at the end of the string
- `:`: literal colon

Comment: I was able to use @rakesh answer and get mine to work. But thank you so much for your response! Do you mind explaining what (r'(.+) \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$') does?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def filter_date(date):
    match = re.search(r'\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', date)
    return date.replace(match.group(), '').strip() if match else date

xs = ['String 1', 'String2', 'String 3 05.24.2019 04:48:24']
out = list(map(filter_date, xs))

print(out)
```

**Output:**

```
['String 1', 'String2', 'String 3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution, without a compiled regex and with a clear regex syntax.
It is less generic, it works only with you precise input, a string followed by a space and the date-time format as specified.

```py
import re

def remove_date(s): 
    if re.search("\d\d:\d\d:\d\d$", s): return s[:-20]  // remove the last 20 characters
    else: return s

sampleString = ['String 1', 'String2', 'String 3 05.24.2019 04:48:24'] 
sampleString = list(map(remove_date, sampleString))

print(sampleString)
```

What is [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) ?
To play with regex: https://regexr.com/